# Sql 2008R2 Max()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a function in which I have written the following lines.

```
DECLARE @MaxLetterID BigInt;
DECLARE @MaxObserverLetterID BigInt;
DECLARE @MaxBillLetterID bigInt;

SET @MaxLetterID = (SELECT     MAX(LetterNO) AS Expr1
                    FROM         Lab
                    WHERE     (LetterNO BETWEEN @Min AND @Max));

SET @MaxObserverLetterID = (SELECT     MAX(LetterNO) AS Expr1
                    FROM         ObserverCoReq
                    WHERE     (LetterNO BETWEEN @Min AND @Max));

SET @MaxBillLetterID =(SELECT     MAX(LetterNO) AS Expr1
                    FROM         BillLetters
                    WHERE     (LetterNO BETWEEN @Min AND @Max));

SET @FinalID=MAX(@MaxLetterID,@MaxObserverLetterID,@MaxBillLetterID)
```

am I right with the last line? can I use Max function like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You would need a `greatest` funxtion which SQL Server does not have. But this

```
select @FinalID = max(c)  
from 
(
     select @MaxLetterID as c
     union  
     select @MaxObserverLetterID as c
     union
     select @MaxBillLetterID as c
) x
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27009)

Comment: sorry if it is a silly question. but what is 'x' at the end for?

Comment: It is an alias name. You need to give subqueries a name.

Comment: I have change my code to yours but it returns NULL. is '@FinalID=Max(c)' equivalent to 'SET @FinalID=Max(c)' ?

Comment: 'select FinalID = max(c)  
from 
(
  select MaxLetterID as c
  union  
  select MaxObserverLetterID as c
  union
  select MaxBillLetterID as c
) x
SET FinalID = FinalID + 1;
RETURN FinalID'

Comment: did you forget the `@`?

Comment: No! that is because SO didn't let me to add '@'

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in the SQLFiddle I provided? Modify it and post the link.

Comment: Is that possible to Debug my function in SQL or Visual Studio?

Comment: Not really. You can add `print`s or `select`s to your script to output something in runtime.